# Set a hidden string value to an entry box in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make my own spin on Hangman. A basic part of Hangman is that the user guesses a letter and if it is there, it appears in the entry box else it gets added to a list of incorrect guesses.

What I want to do now is assign a letter to each read-only entry box based on the random word generated. However, I also don't want the user to know what letter is assigned to it (obviously).

```
def press(num):
    string1 = " "
    string1+=str(num)
    appears.set(string1)

appears = StringVar()
entrybox = Entry(hangman,state= 'readonly',textvariable = appears)
entrybox.place(x = 0, y = 0)

q = Button(hangman, text = 'Q', width = 4, command = lambda : press('Q'))
q.place(x = 200, y = 440)
```

This is what i've managed to do so far

Comment: `entrybox.hidden_letter = word[x]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store a mapping from letters to StringVars. Then, look up the guessed letter and replace the text from a placeholder to the letter.

```
word = "tiger" # just an example

let2svar = {}

for let in word:
  svar = StringVar()
  svar.set("_")
  entrybox = Entry(hangman, state='readonly', textvariable=svar)
  entrybox.place(x=0, y=0)
  if let not in let2svar:
    let2svar[let] = []

  let2svar[let].append(svar)


# Now when user guesses letter 'guess', check if it is in the word.

if guess in let2svar:
  for svar in let2svar[guess]:
    svar.set(guess)
```

You can also check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict for a cleaner way to handle the dictionary.